# AsyncTask doInBackground odd behavior

Tags: android, android-asynctask, backgroundworker

**ORIGINAL**
I have an AsyncTask which performs network requests, and it works fine.  The environment I'm testing in is against Eclipse with the USB wired to the device to log information to LogCat.  When detaching the USB wire from the device and re-attaching the wire back to the device I can see the LogCat session resume, afterwards, I exit the application and re-enter the application, and when the AsyncTask runs again, the network request fails.

**Has anyone ever experienced odd behavior when performing network calls in between detaching and re-attaching the USB wire to the android device?**  The flow of the application appears normal as I've logged about every sequence up to the point & through the point of the AsyncTask executing.  **The application is functional with the network calls when the USB is wired at all times.**  Might the LogCat have anything to do with this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**
The network request does not actually fail, the server just responds with an error code.  But before I could start blaming the server, I performed multiple hits successfully through the browser to the same URL.  I've only involved the USB into the picture, because the odd behavior only occurs when the USB is detached from the device and re-attached.

**UPDATE**
After doing further research, I've finally diagnosed the issue but have no idea why it's so.  When the debugger is attached to the process responsible for handling the network calls (background threads), the application works as expected.  However, when the debugger is disconnected from the process, the network calls brings back the server error results.

**How is the debugger influencing the network calls?**

Comment: You are saying that you exit the application and come back in. That sounds more likely to be the culprit of why things are failing. Have you debugged this at all ?

Comment: How do you know the request fails?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've found the answer and I'll post it up just in case anyone happens to run into this issue.

Essentially, USB wire didn't really play a role, it was just the server spitting back bad data, and a simple retry after failure solved it.  The reason it took time to understand was because while the device was attached using the USB, the behavior is normal and all is well.  This gave the illusion that the server isn't the issue as it worked consistently.  However, I'm aware in "Debug" mode, execution is slower, this may have allowed the server some time to rest upon subsequent requests, giving the illusion that the server is reactive.  However, when detaching the USB wire from the device, and thereby exiting debug mode and escaping from the less speedy environment, the server was really put to the test & failed.  So whoever runs into this issue, don't think the debugger is causing the issue, it's most likely the server.